# adding entity framework as a nuget vs manual in azure function project visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, azure, nuget, azure-functions

I created a azure function project (visual studio 2017) to create a azure function. I want to add entity framework to connect to my db, so I googled around and see [tutorials](https://serversncode.com/azure-functions-with-entity-framework-part-1/) tell me to add these manual lines to the `project.json` file

```json
{
 "frameworks": 
 {  
  "net46":
  { 
   "dependencies":
   {
     "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.3",
     "EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
     "System.Data.Common": "4.3.0"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Question 1 - why can't I just add the nuget for entity to the azure function project? It looks like I can in the nuget package manager!

Question 2 - if adding a nuget isn't the correct way to add entity framework to a azure function project, which file is the 'project.json' file? In my project I have a 'host.json' file and a 'local.settings.json' file. Additionaly if it goes in the host.json file what schema do I use. I'm not sure how this works but it looks like there are different schemas where I can put code.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is aimed at C# scripts `csx` Functions made in the portal. If you are using Visual Studio to create pre-compiled functions, you should use normal way to reference NuGet packages. `project.json` is not applicable.